# How to show that $at^2+bt+c$ can be written as $\displaystyle \begin{equation} a \left( t+\frac{b}{2a}\right) ^2-\frac{1}{4a}(b^2-4ac)\end{equation}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've just expanded

$$\displaystyle \begin{equation} a \left( t+\frac{b}{2a}\right) ^2-\frac{1}{4a}(b^2-4ac)\end{equation}\tag{1}$$

to

$$at^2+bt+c\tag{2}$$

but I guess that perhaps showing it would be about turning $(2)$ to $(1)$ and for this, I have no idea on how it should be done. Is what I did enough or do I have to do the other way arround as I suggested?

Comment: Equality ($=$) works both ways. It doesn't matter what side you start.

Comment: Expanding is perfectly correct. Note that we need $a\ne 0$.

Comment: For using the completing the square procedure, and generalizations, you will need to be familiar with the process in the other direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is completing the square $$at^2+b t+c=a\Big(t^2+\frac{b}{a}+\frac{c}{a}\Big)$$ Now $$t^2+\frac{b}{a}t=\Big(t+\frac{b}{2a}\Big)^2-\Big(\frac{b}{2a}\Big)^2$$ I let you continuing

Answer (score 2):

Write down $$at^2+bt+c=a(t+x)^2+y,$$ that is, $$at^2+bt+c=a(t+x)^2+y=at^2+2axt+x^2+y.$$ Simplify $at^2.$ If you compare terms with $t$ you get $b=2ax$ and, finally, $c=y+x^2.$

Can you finish now?